# Netbeans detect javascript alias tag?

Tags: alias, netbeans

Netbeans will apply the appropriate formatting and parsing when it loads a `.js` file of detects `<script>` tags in the current `.html` or `.php` file I am working in.

I am using Zend Framework 2 to build an application in Netbeans, and one of the features is to add javascript to a view page but only render it in the main layout. The function to do this is:

`<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureStart(); ?>`

and

`<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureEnd(); ?>`

(with my js in the middle).

Obviously Netbeans doesn't recognise this as javascript as a) this is a `.phtml` file, and b) there is no `script` tag. As such, there is no formatting, background parsing or function autocomplete.

How do I set the above function lines as alias tags for `<script>` and `</script>` in Netbeans so when I use them I get the full js experience?

I am using Netbeans 8.1, and have looked in the `Tools` -> `Options` but couldn't find an obvious place to add this.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a way to add alternative open/close tags for languages (that I've been able to locate). As an alternative, I can do the following:

Something like this:

```
<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureStart(); ?>
//<script type="text/javascript">

// my code here    

//</script>
<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureEnd(); ?>
```

Of course it will produce two useless lines in the JS output.

### Why does this work?

`//` is not used in regular html as a comment, and because it does not detect my php functions as javascript it allows me to use them as content. Following that, the `<script>` tags are inserted into the `inlineScript` where the `//` IS a comment command, so the `<script>` tags are ignored.

#### Is there an alternative solution that I've overlooked?